# Checkbox in PeopleSoft fluid page

Tags: fluid-layout, peoplesoft

Does anyone here know how to create check box in a fluid peoplesoft page, and how to incorporate it with a SQLExec in my peoplecode. For example, if for a student he pulls 5 programs then the checkbox in the fluid page should also be 5.

Is that possible? Please help

Comment: Thanks man, that really did help.

Answer (score 1):

Grids still work in fluid.

Put the checkbox in a grid. Let a view with the programs populate the grid.

5 programs -> 5 grid rows -> 5 checkboxes